# Wrapper classes to avoid package changes in common-lang

Tags: java, apache, refactoring, package

1. We are using common-lang dependency and its classes in 6 different modules. Since new dependency have package changes i.e. org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils to org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils. So we have to refactor complete code base.
2. To avoid above issue we decided to create a project specific StringUtils class which will internally invoke org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils, So in future if any package structure changes we can only make changes in single class.

All methods in org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils are static methods

What will be the best approach to create a wrapper class here? 
can we do `class StringUtils extends org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils` and keep everything empty?
There and more classes also for which we may need to write wrapper methods/classes.

Comment: Why can't you keep both dependecies?

Comment: Then project will unnecessarily depends on to many third party dependencies. Also there are chances that development team use any of the class since both in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest is to search/replace the package `org.apache.commons.lang` by `org.apache.commons.lang3` in the whole project.
The next time such change happens, it is super to apply a similar change.

Not sure why you seem reluctant to do this?

Comment: I am thinking that creating a helper class will make minimum impact if any changes occurs. Also If I want to switch to any other library that will save my time since I just need to modify one class not complete code base

Comment: I think this is lots of ifs and buts, but no real need. YAGNI and Occam's razor are your friends here. Just do the global search/replace and move on. If it finally happens that more changes are required in the future, then it will be the right time to see how to do it, but do not plan now for the unexpected.